# Why is my span tag here aligned with a button? I seemingly have not told it to at all in the CSS

Tags: html, css

(Well, I'm sure I have, but I just can't figure out why it's aligned like that.)

See here: http://web.cs.dal.ca/~selig/serverside/assignment2/

I would provide CSS but I don't know what's relevant at all. I don't believe I've told it any rules that would align it like that. I want it just centred beneath the two buttons.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not clicking on a random link from an unknown website. Could you provide more details, or replicate the problem on a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Is the one terribly out of place that hard to notice? It's the one under the buttons that is aligned far to the right for some reason.

Comment: Which span? Aligned how? How does this differ from what you expect? Even if you answer those questions then your question, as it stands, is depends on an external URL that is likely to change and is thus of no long term value to Stackoverflow (so should be closed as *too localised*). You should edit your question to fix that.

Comment: @DougSmith — The "one terribly out of place" is only terribly out of place if you know where it is *supposed* to be.

Comment: @Doug Smith -- This looks like a fishing link. Can you provide an image of what you want ?

Comment: I might be naive to click such a link, but once I did I thought the question description was actually clear enough.

Comment: @freefaller, it's safe.

Have you tried wrapping some of the elements in div's to help structure it how you want?  I don't see anything that would cause it to align like that other than a strange css quirk in how you have it layed out.  Put some more div's in where applicable.

Comment: It's a link from my university's web space, but yeah, the fact that one line of text is pushed way over and overflowing awkwardly to the middle should be fairly obvious. Regardless, I did try divs and CSS manipulation, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, since div#upload is an inline-block, it doesn't make much sense floating it too. If you remove the floating, the span starts behaving (it's aligned with the upload button since they are both pushed to the right by the floating div), but the positioning of the Upload button becomes funny. Changing the vertical alignment of div#upload fixes that somehow.

```
#upload {
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `float: left;` to your span class it should work but could you not close the form tag before your span?

For example:

```
</form>
<span class="valid-formats">Valid input: .txt files &lt;= 512 KB</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is out of controll, i.e. out of flow.

```
.valid-formats {
  clear: both;
  color: #999999;
  float: left;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a table could be used. Example:

```
<table>
  <tr style="vertical-align:top;">
    <td>No file selected</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Browse"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"><br />
      Valid input:<br />
      .txt files &lt;= 512 KB</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You need to add some CSS, but at least I think the alignment is as you want.